# Trouble accumulating data from specific time interval last year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to accumulate an amount from a SQL query. The inputs `@STARTDATE` and `@ENDDATE` is a datetime type (YYYYMMDD).
So the Case statements check if the date of the verification is between the specific dates.

Some explanations of the Case statements:
Works fine:
CURRENT_YEAR_ACC, accumulates the current years amounts of verifications from the beginning of the year to @ENDDATE

CURRENT_YEAR_MONTHS, the accumulated amounts between @STARTDATE and @ENDDATE.

PREVIOUS_YEAR_MONTH, last years accumulated amounts between @STARTDATE -1 yr and @ENDDATE -1 yr.

Does not work:

PREVIOUS_YEAR_ACC, should calculate beginning of last year (20XX-01-01) to the @ENDDATE -1yr.

Here I get the same value as PREVIOUS_YEAR_MONTH

```
   sum (RAW_DATA.CURRENT_YEAR_MONTH) as PERIOD_I_AR,
   sum (RAW_DATA.PREVIOUS_YEAR_MONTH) as PERIOD_FG_AR,
   sum (RAW_DATA.CURRENT_YEAR_ACC) as ACK_I_AR,
   sum (RAW_DATA.PREVIOUS_YEAR_ACC) as ACK_FG_AR
from (SELECT rehuv.[KD1] as VST_nr, rekod.BEN as VST_ben,
   rehuv.KONTO as Konto_nr, rektk.KONTO_BEN as Konto_ben,
   lresk.LEV_NR as LEV_nr, rehuv.TEXT as LEV_ben, rehuv.VER_DATUM
   as DATUM, case when rehuv.VER_DATUM > = dateadd (month,
   - datepart (month, @STARTDATE) + 1, @STARTDATE)
   and rehuv.VER_DATUM < = @ENDDATE then rehuv.BELOPP else 0 end
   as CURRENT_YEAR_ACC,
   case when rehuv.VER_DATUM > = dateadd (YEAR, - 1, dateadd (MONTH, - datepart (MONTH, @STARTDATE) + 1, @STARTDATE)) and rehuv.VER_DATUM < = DATEADD (year, - 1, @ENDDATE) 
then rehuv.BELOPP else 0 end as PREVIOUS_YEAR_ACC,
   case when rehuv.VER_DATUM > = @STARTDATE
   and rehuv.VER_DATUM < = @ENDDATE then rehuv.BELOPP else 0 end
   as CURRENT_YEAR_MONTH,
   case when rehuv.VER_DATUM > = DATEADD (year, - 1, @STARTDATE)
   and rehuv.VER_DATUM < = DATEADD (year, - 1,
   @ENDDATE) then rehuv.BELOPP else 0 end
   as PREVIOUS_YEAR_MONTH FROM [FTG0001].[dbo].[REHUV]
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what an MCVE is. It's an incomplete fragment. MCVE is a minimal, **COMPLETE**, verifiable example. This fragment makes understanding very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to follow the KISS principle (Keep it stupid simple).

The best way in my opinion is to make subqueries, one per time period - filtered on this period. Sum the values and join them with an inner join together and extract the needed columns (sum column). Those many cases can slow it down.

Maybe you need a index on the date column to improve the performance further. But this needs to be tested in your environment.